# How to use function cv.glm - Error loading it

Tags: r

I am trying to use the function cv.glm but it returns an error that the function was not found. How can I fix this problem?

```
rm(list = ls())

cat("\014")

set.seed(7)
x=rnorm(150)
y=x-2*x^2+rnorm(150)
Data <- data.frame(x, y)
fit.glm.1 <- glm(y ~ x)
a <- cv.glm(Data, fit.glm.1)$delta[1]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean removing the ` ?

Lets try `a <- cv.glm(Data, fit.glm.1)$delta[1]`?

:-)Your code works well

Comment: If the error message is `could not find function "cv.glm"`, it suggests that you need `library(boot)`. The function `cv.glm` is in this package.